# How to hide text when a div translates over it on hover?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

My preview div items are scaling on hover. What I want is to turn the opacity for title to zero when the first child is hovered upon. Is there any easy way to do this?

Right now it looks like this - https://i.ibb.co/mF64DdR/Screenshot-28.png

```
<div className="collection-preview">
<h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
  <div className="preview"> 
  {     
        movies
        ? (movieData.map(({id, ...otherProps}) => <CollectionItem key={id} {...otherProps} />))
        : null
  }
  {
        tvshow
        ? (tvData.map(({id, ...otherProps}) => <CollectionItem key={id} {...otherProps} />))
        : null
  }
  </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: do you want to hide the h1 tag?

Comment: Yes the h1 tag while first child of preview div is hovered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
let title = document.querySelector('.title');
let preview = document.querySelector('.preview');
preview.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
   title.setAttribute("style", "opacity:0;")
})
```

However, I would add a class to each CollectionItem so you could add the eventListener to each preview item instead of the parent.

If you are using react hooks you could also use useHover. https://usehooks.com/useHover/

Comment: This isn't the React way. Why are you picking up elements with DOM selectors, and using event listeners like that?

Comment: Because the op didn't specify that he needed a React only solution? I did also provide a link for the best way to do it in React in my opinion.

Comment: The code is React-like, and the OP used a React tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use CSS to hide any text on hover

```
.title:hover{
   display: none;
}
```